# Keep-alive query failed

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, ubuntu, pycharm

I use PyCharm Professionals IDE and I am trying to connect mongoDB container to pycharm. I get  keep alive query error .

```
DBMS: Mongo DB (no ver.)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=mixed
Driver: MongoDB JDBC Driver (ver. 1.18, JDBC4.2)
Effective version: UNKNOWN (ver. 0.0)

Ping: 10 sec, 795 ms (keep-alive query results in error)

Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}].
```

driver change keep-alive query

When I click to driver change keep-alive query , keep-alive query section is empty.While I doing these my mongo container is open and running on back side. I am beginner so I can not see my mistake. If you help me I would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## Try This

```
mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@localhost:27017/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

change the `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`
past this uri in the `Pycharm url`

[image]

And click the `Test Connection`